# Customize magento Registration form

Tags: magento-1.9, php, extensions

### Where "Get Social" extention is shown ?

I have installed Get Social extention for magento 1.9

It is not getting displayed at the **Admin** end.

Comment: It shows any error

Comment: Refresh cache and check.

Comment: @Kothari It doesn't show any error

Comment: Check your system.xml for admin menu

Comment: is this issue still running ?

Comment: Yes vaibhav. Its not showing in admin panel